# How do I select record except specific field

Tags: sql-server

I want to select a record and with exception to specific fields.

```
SELECT * FROM tb_Account EXCEPT name="me"
```

Is there's a statement for that?

Thanks! in advance.

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you are trying to do? You want to get all rows that have a name different than 'me'? or a column != 'me'?

Comment: If you are trying to provide results that omit sensitive information, e.g. employees without salary, you might want a VIEW.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tb_Account WHERE name <> 'me'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do is this:

```
SELECT 'SELECT ' +
    STUFF ((
        SELECT ', [' + name + ']'
        FROM syscolumns
        WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('tb_Account') AND
            name <> 'me'
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') +
    ' FROM [tb_Account]'
```

That would generate a `SELECT` statement. Then you could execute that like this:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' +
    STUFF ((
        SELECT ', [' + name + ']'
        FROM syscolumns
        WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('tb_Account') AND
            name <> 'me'
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') +
    ' FROM [tb_Account]'

EXECUTE (@sql)
```